# Python2 kernel is actually Python3 in JupyterHub

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyterhub

In trying to set up a python 2 kernel for my JupyterHub instance, I've added the following code to the Dockerfile for one of the images I'd like to run:

```
RUN pip install -U ipython
RUN python2 -m pip install ipykernel
RUN python2 -m ipykernel install --user
```

Which I got from here: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html

However, when I launch Jupyterhub I still see the image as running python 3, despite me having selected the "Python 2" kernel:
[image]

Inside my docker container / notebook environment in `/usr/share/jupyter/kernels` I see this:

```
sh-4.2$ pwd
/usr/share/jupyter/kernels
sh-4.2$ ls
python2  python3
```

When I got into `python2` I see a `kernel.json` file with the following in it:

```
{
 "display_name": "Python 2",
 "language": "python",
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ]
}
```

And sure enough, the output of `python --version` is `Python 2.7.5`.

However, when I launch a notebook and inspect `/proc/{pid}/cmdline` I see that the kernel for `Python 2` was launched using the binary in `/usr/bin/python3.4`, which is obviously *not* Python 2.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does your `kernel.json` say for the `Python 2`. You may want to give it an explicit name with `--display-name <NAME>` in addition to `--user` to see if it is picking up your user kernel.

Comment: @AChampion I've tried running with `--name test` and sure enough it appears, plus the output of `sys.executable` is now `'/usr/bin/python2'`.